# python boto - AWS S3 access without a bucket name

Tags: python, amazon-s3, path, boto, bucket

I have credentials ('aws access key', 'aws secret key', and a path) for a dataset stored on AWS S3. I can access the data by using CyberDuck or FileZilla Pro.

I would like to automate the data fetch stage and using Python/Anaconda, which comes with boto2, for this purpose.

I do not have a "bucket" name, just a path in the form of /folder1/folder2/folder3 and I could not find a way to access the data without a "bucket name" with the API.

Is there a way to access S3 programatically without having a "bucket name", i.e. with a path instead?

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible to access the objects without knowing the bucket name. Try digging into CyberDuck or FileZilla Pro to find the bucket name.

Comment: Please strongly consider using boto3, as boto is unmaintained and had its latest release three years ago.

Comment: If your path looks like `s3://foo/bar`, then then the first parameter is actually the bucket name: `s3://bucket-name/folder/object`

Comment: @Dunedan - `boto` is what comes with Anaconda3, which is the only available Python package for our machines. I am not sure whether I have the ability to install new packages on to this machine.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - do you mean there is a way to convert the "path" to a "bucket name"? Or shall I look into wireshark logs for my CyberDuck connection etc to find out whether the tool converts it into a bucket name

Comment: I'm saying that, if the connection string starts with `s3://`, then the next element is the bucket name.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - thanks. The URL I have is https://s3.amazonaws.com/ and I use port 443. Then I type in a path, which I think is the client specific location on the S3 storage- any ways to extract a bucket name you can think of?

Comment: I'm suggesting that the bucket name is the first path of the path you have been given: `s3.amazon.com/bucket-name/path/object`

Answer (score 2):

s3 does not have a typical native directory/folder structure, instead, it is defined with keys. If the URL starts with `s3://dir_name/folder_name/file_name`, it means dir_name is nothing but a bucket name. If you are not sure about bucket name but have s3 access parameters and path, then you can

1. List all the s3_buckets available -

   s3 = boto3.client('s3')

   response = s3.list_buckets()
2. Use s3.client.head_object() method recursively for each bucket with your path as key.